# Recursive result of a custom field

Tags: t-sql, sql-server-2008-r2

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DHK53.png)[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JwYEn.png)I need each level to be the sum set in the calculation field. These can be positive or negative.

I have included a simplified version of the structure of my table and some sample data and what I would like to produce.

```
CREATE TABLE ACCOUNT_TEST([ID] [int] IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL, CODE VARCHAR(12), AMMOUNT MONEY)

    INSERT INTO ACCOUNT_TEST(CODE,AMMOUNT) VALUES(200, 3)
    INSERT INTO ACCOUNT_TEST(CODE,AMMOUNT) VALUES(205, 2)
    INSERT INTO ACCOUNT_TEST(CODE,AMMOUNT) VALUES(300, 20)
    INSERT INTO ACCOUNT_TEST(CODE,AMMOUNT) VALUES(400, 4)
    INSERT INTO ACCOUNT_TEST(CODE,AMMOUNT) VALUES(410, 4)
    INSERT INTO ACCOUNT_TEST(CODE,AMMOUNT) VALUES(420, 4)
    INSERT INTO ACCOUNT_TEST(CODE,AMMOUNT) VALUES(450, 3)
    INSERT INTO ACCOUNT_TEST(CODE,AMMOUNT) VALUES(700, 25)
    INSERT INTO ACCOUNT_TEST(CODE,AMMOUNT) VALUES(710, 30)

    CREATE TABLE [dbo].[BALANCE_TEST]([ID] [int] IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL,
        [POSITION] [int] NOT NULL,
        [TITLE] [nvarchar](200) NULL,
        [AMMOUNT] [money] NULL,
        [IDENTIFIER] [nvarchar](10) NULL,
        [CALCULATION] [nvarchar](255) NULL,
        [ACCOUNTS] nvarchar(300));

    INSERT INTO BALANCE_TEST(POSITION,TITLE,AMMOUNT,IDENTIFIER,CALCULATION,ACCOUNTS) VALUES(1,'  A)',0,'A','AI',null)
    INSERT INTO BALANCE_TEST(POSITION,TITLE,AMMOUNT,IDENTIFIER,CALCULATION,ACCOUNTS) VALUES(2,'     I.',0,'AI','AI1+AI2',null)
    INSERT INTO BALANCE_TEST(POSITION,TITLE,AMMOUNT,IDENTIFIER,CALCULATION,ACCOUNTS) VALUES(3,'                1.',5,'AI1',NULL,'200,205')
    INSERT INTO BALANCE_TEST(POSITION,TITLE,AMMOUNT,IDENTIFIER,CALCULATION,ACCOUNTS) VALUES(4,'                2.',20,'AI2',NULL,'300')
    INSERT INTO BALANCE_TEST(POSITION,TITLE,AMMOUNT,IDENTIFIER,CALCULATION,ACCOUNTS) VALUES(5,'  B)',0,'B','BI+BII',null)
    INSERT INTO BALANCE_TEST(POSITION,TITLE,AMMOUNT,IDENTIFIER,CALCULATION,ACCOUNTS) VALUES(6,'     I.',15,'BI',NULL,'400,410,420,450')
    INSERT INTO BALANCE_TEST(POSITION,TITLE,AMMOUNT,IDENTIFIER,CALCULATION,ACCOUNTS) VALUES(7,'     II.',0,'BII','BII1+BII2',null)
    INSERT INTO BALANCE_TEST(POSITION,TITLE,AMMOUNT,IDENTIFIER,CALCULATION,ACCOUNTS) VALUES(8,'                1.',25,'BII1',NULL,'700')
    INSERT INTO BALANCE_TEST(POSITION,TITLE,AMMOUNT,IDENTIFIER,CALCULATION,ACCOUNTS) VALUES(9,'                2.',30,'BII2',NULL,'710')
    INSERT INTO BALANCE_TEST(POSITION,TITLE,AMMOUNT,IDENTIFIER,CALCULATION,ACCOUNTS) VALUES(10,'  TOTAL (A - B)',0,'TOTAL_AB','A-B',null)
```

Results
I update manually so that you can see the expected result.

```
    UPDATE BALANCE_TEST SET AMMOUNT = (SELECT SUM(AMMOUNT) FROM BALANCE_TEST WHERE ID IN(3,4)) WHERE ID = 2
    UPDATE BALANCE_TEST SET AMMOUNT = (SELECT SUM(AMMOUNT) FROM BALANCE_TEST WHERE ID IN(2)) WHERE ID = 1
    UPDATE BALANCE_TEST SET AMMOUNT = (SELECT SUM(AMMOUNT) FROM BALANCE_TEST WHERE ID IN(8,9)) WHERE ID = 7
    UPDATE BALANCE_TEST SET AMMOUNT = (SELECT SUM(AMMOUNT) FROM BALANCE_TEST WHERE ID IN(6,7)) WHERE ID = 5
    UPDATE BALANCE_TEST SET AMMOUNT = (SELECT SUM(AMMOUNT) FROM BALANCE_TEST WHERE ID IN(2)) WHERE ID = 1
    UPDATE BALANCE_TEST SET AMMOUNT = (SELECT AMMOUNT FROM BALANCE_TEST WHERE ID = 1) - (SELECT AMMOUNT FROM BALANCE_TEST WHERE ID = 5) WHERE ID = 10
```

Thank you.

Comment: can you please format the desired result properly thanks

Comment: I expanded the code to explain myself better.
Ammount of the table balance_test comes from the sum of the table account_test being the sum of the codes included in the field accounts of the table balance_test

Answer (score 0):

Juanma, Thx for adding the DDL together with sample data. Much better question now...

But: What you are trying to achieve is closer to something like Excel, might be that you have something in mind like an [expression tree](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/concepts/expression-trees/).

SQL-Server is the wrong tool to do this: You *can* cut bread with a chainsaw, but the result will not be very convincing.

You might use SQL-Server to model the underlying meta-data and the data you want to compute, but you should use a proper programming language to interpret and calculate this.

Some major flaws:

- **Never** store comma separated values (e.g. `200,205` is breaking 1.NF). This must be stored in a related table with a foreign key.
- Same with `AI1+AI2`: This must be stored in a `term1,term2,operator` structure.
- Don's use `money`, rather use `decimal(10,4)`
- Do not construct a hierarchy with chapter-like numbers and indentation.

  - Rather use a self-referencing table (read about [HIERARCHYID](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/data-types/hierarchyid-data-type-method-reference?view=sql-server-2017)) to construct an infint hierarchy or
  - a bunch of joinable tables, sub-tables and sub-sub-tables if there is a maximum depth
- Try to understand the inner construction of an expression tree to build your tables after that.

Good luck! This is - at least as I understand it - not trivial...